# Creating new column based on another column value with two conditions and converting NaN to blank

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a minor issue with pandas code. I am using the np.where command to create a new column based on conditions and return either 1 or 0. However with np.where, the NaN values are returned as 0, but I would like to return them as blanks. If I understood correctly with np.where it is not straightforwardly possible. The x y z q is defined as the index. I can achieve this with the following:

```
   column1
x    NaN
y    Yes
z    No
q    Maybe

df.fillna("EMPTY", inplace=True)
df["column2"] = np.where((df["column1"]=="Yes")|(df["column1"]=="Maybe"), 1, np.where(df["column1"]=="EMPTY", "", 0)) 

   column1   column2
x   EMPTY       ""  
y   Yes         1 
z   No          0
q   Maybe       1
```

So it tests whether column1 contains the value "Yes" or "Maybe" and if true returns 1 and if false checks whether it contains "EMPTY" if true returns blank and if false returns 0. I use fillna to replace the blank NaN with EMPTY. This works but when writing it to excel all values are stored as text instead of numbers most likely because I use "" to fill in blanks in rows where the value was EMPTY (originally NaN).

This can be solved with pd.to_numeric which converts the values to 1.0 and 0.0 and creates NaN over blanks. When again using fillna("") I am able to come up with the requested result, but is there more efficient way to achieve the following result? It is important that the values are stored as numbers when importing the data frame to excel, and NaN values are blanks.

Comment: use `df.replace` with a dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there more efficient way to achieve the following result?

Yes. One way is to pass a `dict` to `df.replace`, and it should work nicely.

```
x = {np.nan: '', 'No': 0, 'Yes': 1, 'Maybe': 1}
df.replace(x)

  column1
x        
y       1
z       0
q       1
```

If you want this applied on a single column, the procedure is the same. Just assign the result back later.

```
df.column1 = df.column1.replace(x)
df

  column1
x        
y       1
z       0
q       1
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I did not even realize that I could use just replace here, now it makes perfect sense. Worked perfectly and definitely more efficient than what I tried.